# How to set default theme in material theme UI jetbrains rider

Tags: macos, rider

I want to have GitHub light theme as default. When I close and start IDE, instead of previously used GitHub theme plugin activate IntelliJ Light theme.

Comment: Color scheme settings are saved in `%APPDATA%\JetBrains\Rider2022.1\options\colors.scheme.xml` (on Windows). Does this file gets updated? And can you also try whether it works with a scheme that gets shipped ootb, e. g. _Rider Dark_?

Comment: I'm sorry, forgot to write that I'm on mac.

Comment: Did you search for an equally named file? I doubt that JetBrains uses a completely different configuration pattern just for another OS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I applied it using material theme picker button. But for saving after restart, I had needed to do it from material theme settings.